# Excel: A function that can be duplicated down a column that will result in the sorted the values of some other column

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a spread sheet with a large amount of numbers in column A. I want column B to contain the sorted values (from largest to smallest) of column A.

I know this can be done by copying the numbers from column A to column B, and then sort column B. Is there a way to do this automatically, without using VBA?

I want column B to update when values in column A is replaced.

Comment: Depending on what else you want to do with this list, you can use the Small() function

Comment: Have a look at the [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db) and the [SMALL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy if we assign a rank to each value in column **A**.  In **C1** enter:

```
=RANK(A1,A:A,0)+COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A1)-1
```

and copy down.  In **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(),C:C,0))
```

and copy down.  For example:

[image]

There are simpler methods using either *Large()* or *Small()*, but you must be careful to insure they will handle duplicated values in column **A**